# How to center the left floated items in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the below code in my CSS file which results in my grid/box items displaying to the left of the webpage. However I'd like them to be centered. I tried removing float;left and many alternatives but nothing works. What can I add/remove from the below to center them?

GRID:

```
width:170px;
height:235px;
background:#f4f4f4;
border:1px solid #dedede;
padding:4px;
border-radius:4px;
text-align: center;
float:left;
margin:9px;
margin-bottom:20px;
position:relative
```

and XX>LI:

```
display: block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
margin-top: 0px; 
overflow:hidden
```

Comment: you really should provide some of your HTML, and what has this question to do with PHP?

Comment: @sam please make a demo with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you wish to use flex-boxes ( which make this very easy ) usually I would try something along the following lines. It is the `margin:9px auto` combined with `float:none` that does the trick:

```
.centred{
    display:block;
    float:none;
    /* a combination of float:none and left/right margin of auto */
    margin:9px auto;

    width:170px;
    height:235px;
    background:#f4f4f4;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
    padding:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    text-align: center;


    margin-bottom:20px;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood what you're asking, you should remove the `float: left` on the element and put `display: inline-block`, then `text-align: center` on the container

http://jsfiddle.net/2t523d92/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to html simply

```
<center>text</center>
```

or

if you still want to use CSS remove

```
float: left;
```

and add

```
display: inline-block; 
text-align: center;
```

Comment: the `center` tag is deprecated, you should always use css for styling stuff, not html!

Comment: I tried all of the above and they all failed. The page displays nicely on the PC but it drifts to the left when viewed on a phone and I'd really like it to center. This is the HTML on the index page:

            <li class="widget-container latest-posted-services-big">
          <?php
    
     include 'latest-posted-services.php'; 
    
    ?>
         </li>
            <li class="widget-container latest-posted-tasks-big">
          <?php
    
     include 'latest-posted-tasks.php';
    
    ?>
         </li>

Comment: @Mattia Nocerino, deprecated or not, it is still working on all browsers.

Comment: Yeah, like the `marquee` tag for example, but you should never use those tags in new projects because you don't know how new broswers are going to behave with older tags.

Comment: I'd have to agree. I guess I'm old school :)